# Could not find the Conceptual Schema node to embed as a resource for input file

Tags: build, error-handling, schema

Just updated to .NET 4.5 framework with Entity Framework 5.0 and am getting the following errors when trying to build:

- Could not find the Conceptual Schema node to embed as a resource for input file 'E:\Builds\1\Mobooka v2\Mobooka.Services\Sources\Mobooka.DAL\Tracking.edmx'.
- Could not find the Storage Schema node to embed as a resource for input file 'E:\Builds\1\Mobooka v2\Mobooka.Services\Sources\Mobooka.DAL\Tracking.edmx'.
- Could not find the Mapping node to embed as a resource for input file 'E:\Builds\1\Mobooka v2\Mobooka.Services\Sources\Mobooka.DAL\Tracking.edmx'.

Ive only found about 3 posts through google relating to this problem with none of them providing a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I created an issue for it https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1880

Answer (score 8):

Are you running into this problem when building on TFS?

If so, I experienced the same problem today:

```
Could not find the Conceptual Schema node to embed as a resource for input file ...
Could not find the Storage Schema node to embed as a resource for input file ...
Could not find the Mapping node to embed as a resource for input file ...
```

Our [resident build expert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200936/christopher-painter) informed me the TFS build server did not have .NET 4.5 loaded.

To resolve the problem, I set the project properties to .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 4.5, regenerated my EDMX file/service, and successfully built/checked-in.

Comment: I have had this same problem.  It can also happen when your build server is 32 bit and your developer computer is 64 bit.

Comment: After installing .NET 4.5 is installed, even though the target framework is 4.0 it works on the build server.

Answer (score 2):

Is .NET 4.5 installed on your server machine?

In my case, [.NET 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) was not installed on the build server.  Although @Mike's answer indicates that you can instead build against v4.0, simply installing the .NET framework 4.5 on the build server solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

.net 4.5 is not installed on our build server, my projects are all targetting .net 4 and I am not in a position to update the framework version on the build server.

In my situation I downgraded the edmx file by editing the xml namespaces.

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
```

Became:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx">
```

And:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm"

xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
```

Became:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false"

xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
```

Comment: Did the namespace change *from* 2008/09 *to* 2009/11? Or is it the other way?