# Unable to load the specified metadata resource?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Visual studio to build my REST Api. My project actually has two sub-projects, one is Entity framework and other is Asp.net web api. I have migrated my asp.net web api project from Windows to Mac. I have installed Visual Studio on Mac and debug it successfully. But when I run my api it shows exception:

**ExceptionMessage**: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

**ExceptionType**: System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException.

I have explore this exception and try many solution but still I have a problem. I have tried:

1: [EDMX Problem: change connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689505/5269722)

2: [2nd solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31182321/5269722)

3: [3rd solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1137126/5269722)

4: [4th solution](https://forums.asp.net/t/2012673.aspx?An%20exception%20of%20type%20System%20Data%20Entity%20Core%20MetadataException%20occurred%20in%20EntityFramework%20dll%20but%20was%20not%20handled%20in%20user%20code)

Also when I see on my Asp.net web api project references, System.Web.Entity reference shows error "Assembly not found for framework .Net Framework 4.6"

And I have tried many solution for this exception as well.
I have followed:

[Installing Developer Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549053/5269722)

I have tried to install Developer Pack but it has only windows version.

How can I fix it.

Comment: If you are trying to use deployed database. Than check your connection string again.